# Looking for recommendation for legislations in the tech sector

Tags: united-states, european-union

I am new to the law field. Currently I am a Software Engineer, who is interested in new legislation in the tech sector. I am primary interested in topics concerning the EU and US, as this are the markets my company is working on. Is there some place where I can find most of the new laws and legislations for the tech sector? Let's say like https://thehackernews.com/ for security. I am interested in things like this: https://usa.visa.com/dam/VCOM/global/support-legal/documents/visa-new-subscription-rules-flier.pdf

I have searched to no avail. I failed to find some good source of legal tech news. Do such place even exist? If this question is not for here, let me know and I will delete it.

EDIT: 
TO answer @Iñaki Viggers. I am pretty much interested in anything concerning the tech sector TBH, from Apple getting sued for slowing down IPhones to the new Visa requirements, to let's say even Art 13. It does not have to be a single "all-you-need-to-know compilation". It could be let's say 10 different sources, that I need to check daily or something like this. To rephrase my question in one sentence, if you want to look for any legal changes or news in the Tech Sector, where would you look?

Comment: Your question is certainly on topic. However it does not seem answerable because it is too broad. Technology issues inevitably touch on many other fields: copyright, compliance, financial & accounting, contracts, privacy & data protection laws, the penal code of each jurisdiction, and so forth. I doubt there is an *all-you-need-to-know* compilation of IT laws, or that such compilation is even feasible. The term "*software engineering*" itself is too broad. You might want to narrow down the scope of your question.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I had the question edited